# Trouble with css float on site

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hello i am making a site http://guesthousecontrasts.com however for some reason the content div won't fill the whole page i believe that this is because of some floats i am using, another problem i have is that the content on some pages won't "push" the sticky footer down instead it stays above it, i tried adding clear-fixes to some of the div and adding a clear-fix div at the end of the pages however nothing seems to work so i am kind of lost. I would really appreciate all the help you guys can give and would love to hear any tips/advices/critics you might have.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle showing your problem, this will Reduce the area of concern to the problem only, also your site is not accessible for me sue to some limited access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

width of `.main` div is 1000px; you can keep it whatever you want or 100%.
But the banner image will not fit in that case. Use

```
#banner {
background: url(../images/bg_img2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
padding: 30px 0 0 60px;
background-size: cover;
}
```

to adjust image according to width.

remove margin-bottom from .main-content

```
.main-content {
min-height: calc(100% - 107px); //100% minus 107px of footer
height:auto !important;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

this will solve your footer overlapping problem.

Comment: <code>.main-content {margin: 0 auto -107px;min-height: 100%;}</code> is because of the sticky footer.

Comment: yes the edit one work perfect for the overlapping content, thanks :) now if you can tell me how to force the content div to expand it's height to reach the footer i would be grateful :)

Comment: "content div to expand it's height to reach the footer" means??

Comment: Yes sorry for the vague explanation my English is not that good. What i mean is, for example http://guesthousecontrasts.com/about.html here the div containing the text reaches untill the middle of the page ( the end of the text), and because it have background it looks ugly, i want the div to reach the footer no matter the text, i tried to set the height to 100% but it wont budge, it stays the same.

Comment: You need to chage your HTML markup. keep .body1 i.e. header out of .main-content. set `background:white; /*any color that you want*/width:1000px;`

Answer (score 1):

Only a tip here, stop using floats :P It really can break up an entire site if not properly used or can give you the problems that you have now. I suggest giving the parent div (content):

> position: relative

And the children of that div:

> position: absolute

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<div class="body2">
</div>
```

below

```
<div class="main">
    <section id="content"></content>
</div>
```

This should solve your footer overlapping issue.

To resolve content width issue, you can try below changes,

```
<div class="main">
</div>
```

has below `CSS`

```
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

If you give `width : 100%` it will take size of whole container.

Comment: My issue is with the height not filling the whole site the width is at it should be.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the content height issue?

Comment: On some pages the content div reaches only at the end of the text and because the div have a background it looks ugly i want to expand the div to reach the footer no matter if the text.